# Why can't I see my Numbers spreadsheets on my new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, numbers

I had been using Numbers on my iPad and on my iPhone 4.  The spreadsheets were synced perfectly over 3G and wifi.  However, I just bought an iPhone 4S.  The spreadsheets are missing when I open numbers.  I've tried the following to remedy:

1.) Checked Settings -> iCloud to make sure that my account info was correct.

2.) Checked that Documents & Data were being synced.

3.) Checked that Settings -> Numbers -> Use iCloud was ON.

I'm out of ideas.  I've tried turning these settings off then on again while Numbers had been killed.  Still, I see no spreadsheets on the iPhone.  I can see them on iCloud.com and on my iPad.  What gives?

Comment: I had to wait over 24 hours for a complete sync to occur and then became OK

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to troubleshoot with iCloud syncing and the iOS version of Numbers. (In the sense that even using Xcode to look at the console logs on the device, the error messages are thin to nonexistent.)

When you enable iCloud on one device it should push all the local documents to iCloud so you don't have to connect to iTunes and manage the files manually.

There are three avenues to make the best progress to resolving this issue:

1. Try your account on another device to rule out your account needing attention before you call on Apple for help.
2. Try another account on your device to rule out your device's software or settings (or a very long shot that somehow your hardware could be causing it)
3. Wait it out or [call on Apple to investigate](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/).

Answer (score 1):

Are the spreadsheets there on a computer if you go to the website? If not then they haven't been uploaded, maybe the app crashed or didn't upload them before it closed.
Have you used up all your iCloud storage? It stops syncing if it will go over your limit.

Other than that, I have no idea, other than restore. Bit that's like, last resort. I'd just say email them like you used to.

Answer (score 0):

i've the same issue and I did the below steps:

1- In your iPhone; go to iCloud settings then click on "Delete Account" and keep the files in your iPhone.

2- Go to iCloud settings and enter your ID and Password then accept merging the contents.

3- Open Numbers and accept using iCloud.

Few seconds to get your files :)